# Facebook images on website, editing jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, facebook-graph-api

This is "my code" for pulling images from Facebook and displaying them.

But I want to wrap images around < a href="image.source" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this) >

Please help me outputting:

```
<a href="image.source" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)>
<img src"image.source" width="167" height="167">
</a>
```

Original code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/261512740659107/photos').then(function (response) {

    // 0-8, 0 returns the largest available images, 8 the smallest
    var imageIndex = 4;

    var images = _(response.data)
        .chain()
        .pluck('images')
        .pluck(imageIndex)
        .value();

    console.log(images);

    _(images).each(function (image) {
        $('#image-container').append(
        $('<img>').attr('src', image.source).attr('height', 167).attr('width', 167));
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery wrap() function to put the `<a>` tag around your `<img>` tags.
Just use appendTo() instead to get the instance of the new element so that you can then wrap() it.

```
$.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/261512740659107/photos').then(function (response) {

    // 0-8, 0 returns the largest available images, 8 the smallest
    var imageIndex = 4;

    var images = _(response.data)
        .chain()
        .pluck('images')
        .pluck(imageIndex)
        .value();

    _(images).each(function (image) {
        $($('<img>').attr({'src': image.source, 'height': 167, 'width': 167})).appendTo('#image-container').wrap('<a href="' + image.source + '" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this);" />');
    });
});
```